# Como usar o PHPMailer na estrutura de arquivos MVC

Tags: php, mvc, phpmailer

Estou precisando utilizar o PHPMailer e meu projeto tem a estrutura MVC, porém não sei como organizar os arquivos nos meus models.
tenho a seguinte estrutura de arquivos:

```
root/   
  ajax/   
  controllers/   
  core/
    phpmailer/
        class.phpmailer.php
        class.smtp.php
        PHPMailerAutoload.php
    core.php
    model.php
    controller.php   
  designer/   
  front/   
  models/
     Email.php
```

Com farei?